# Core dump when creating a dynamic sum until eof

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, coredump

The following code has a flaw somewhere and when reaching the 11/12/13 number entering, I get an **Aborted(core dumped)** alert. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    // sum nums until EOF
    int* array; // pointer to the first element
    int size = 10; // memory for 10 elements
    int i = 0, sum = 0;
    array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10); //get memory
    while(scanf("%d",(array + i))!= EOF){   //read until EOF
        //add element to the sum
        sum += *(array+i);

        //realloc memory
        if(i == size-1){
            size *= 2;          
            array = realloc(array, size);   
        }
        i++;
    }
    free(array);        //free the memory
    printf("%d\n\n",sum);   //print sum

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is it crashing? Run your code in a debugger and it'll show you what line it is happening on

Comment: You don't check if `malloc` & friends are successful and wonder why your code crashes? Read [ask] and provide all information. Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: `array = realloc(array, size);` --> `array = realloc(array, size*sizeof(int)); `

Comment: And don't assign the result of `realloc()` before you know whether it succeeded!

Comment: That means always `realloc()` using a *temporary* pointer, so when `realloc()` fails, you don't overwrite your original pointer address with `NULL` creating a *memory-leak*. E.g. `void *tmp = realoc (array, size * sizeof *array); if (tmp == NULL) { perror ("realloc-array"); /* handle error, return, exit, etc... */ } array = tmp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! The realloc should have size*sizeof(int).